# How to set width / max-width for an embedded tweet using Javascript factory function

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, tweets

I am trying to implement embed a tweet with Javascript programmatically.

Below is my code

'''
twttr.widgets
.createTweet(id, tweet, {
conversation: 'none', // or all
cards: 'visible', // or hidden
linkColor: '#cc0000', // default is blue
theme: 'light', // or dark
})
.then(function (el) {
el.querySelector('#twitter-widget-0').style.width = '100%';
});
'''

I have taken reference from below URL

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function

As [twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-parameter-reference) has mentioned that width parameter should be between 250 and 550 pixels.

Is there any way to set width as 100% or Full-Width of web page.

I can't override CSS as all the css has been under iframe.

Any solution ?

Comment: hi, perhaps set the style on the outer iframe?

Comment: I tried that but it is not working .. twitter has set forcefully max-width=550px on/inside iframe css classes